# Try Catch issue with multiple connection string trying in loop until successful

Tags: python

I am using Python to connect to Couchbase Database using below kind of string and the last part of the IP dynamically keep changing so I want to keep trying until successful connect string available:

With below construct the problem is if connection good at IP 10.xxx.xx.112 it is not breaking and its still trying IP 10.xxx.xx.113 and failing as no DB connection available there . I want to break when the good IP and connection available . Please follow the lines after try , except :

I am pretty sure there is better way to write this construct pro grammatically in python but I am missing something .

```
try:
    COUCHBASE_CONNSTR = "couchbase://10.xxx.xx.110:30493"   # From outside the cluster (K8s target IP may not be static always )
    try: 
        COUCHBASE_CONNSTR = "couchbase://10.xxx.xx.111:30493"
        try:
            COUCHBASE_CONNSTR = "couchbase://10.xxx.xx.112:30493"   # From outside the cluster (K8s target IP may not be static always )
            try: 
                COUCHBASE_CONNSTR = "couchbase://10.80.xx.113:30493"
            except:
                print("3")
        except:
            print("4")
    except:
        print("5")
except:
        print("6") 

COUCHBASE_USER = "Administrator"
COUCHBASE_BUCKET_PASSWORD = "password"

cluster = Cluster("COUCHBASE_CONNSTR")
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator(
    "COUCHBASE_USER", "COUCHBASE_BUCKET_PASSWORD"
)
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket("samplebucketname")
```

Comment: Why would assigning a variable to a string create an exception?

Comment: `try` / `except` also has an optional `else` that is executed when no exception occurs. If the construct is used in a loop, the `else` can be a `break` to terminate the loop.

Comment: You need to provide us with your actual connect method! As @DanielWalker already said: your current code cannot throw any exceptions. How are you connecting?

Comment: @amain - this is actual connection method in couchbase ... the problem we are getting is couchbase cluster node IP is not static (specially the last part of the IP) as we have this deployed in Kubernetes cluster and it takes the K8s node IP . For our case we have 6 IP address from where its flipflopping . Port keeps same but IP changes and that is usual for k8s . So my idea was a workaround solution with python connection to connect server from local

Comment: @pauldx Sorry to disappoint you, but assigning a fancy-looking string to a variable doesn't magically initiate a database connection. There must be some kind of *connect* method you are calling (or need to call!) somewhere.

Comment: @amain - Ohh yes you are right , next steps after this string assignment I do below but again main driver is COUCHBASE_CONNSTR ... but I get you what you said let me try to use the same code before doing cluster.authenticate  , cluster = Cluster(app.config["COUCHBASE_CONNSTR"])
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator(
    app.config["COUCHBASE_USER"], app.config["COUCHBASE_BUCKET_PASSWORD"]
)
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket("bucketname", lockmode=LOCKMODE_WAIT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** *Now contains connect procedure.*

Just loop over the address space like this:

```
COUCHBASE_USER = "Administrator"
COUCHBASE_BUCKET_PASSWORD = "password"

authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator(
    COUCHBASE_USER, COUCHBASE_BUCKET_PASSWORD
)

bucket = None

for num in range(110, 255):
    ip = f"10.xxx.xx.{num}"  # <-- replace x with your numbers
    try:
        cluster = Cluster(f"couchbase://{ip}:30493")
        cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
        bucket = cluster.open_bucket("samplebucketname")    

        # this assumes: no exception ==> connected, 
        # better check bucket itself
        print(f"Successfully connected at {ip}")
        break
    except Exception as e: # <-- better specify actual expected exceptions!
        print(f"Could not connect to {ip}: {e}")

# if still not connected
if bucket is None:
    raise ValueError('Could not connect')
```

Comment: Sorry I take it back ... I was overwhelmed with static good node definition of 112 somewhere below to my code so thought it was working ..its NOT

Comment: If I mention : for num in range(112, 113) it works ... where 112 is good node but if I do for num in range(110, 115) it doesn't work

Comment: You need to put the actual connect call inside the try block! Your updated code looks like you need to call `Cluster()`. I just added an example.

Comment: Appreciate that you are trying to help me as best as you can and I copied your modified code ..ran with  , for num in range(112, 113): and it perfectly connects but when I put range(111, 115) it throws error and fails and exited .. so may be this problem is not solving with try catch solution ... ideas ? I am lost

Comment: Appreciate the help ... the final modified code does work

Answer (score 1):

you could define all the urls in a dict and iterate over them,

```
urls = {"couchbase://10.xxx.xx.110:30493": "msg", "couchbase://10.xxx.xx.111:30493": "msg1"}

try:
    for url, msg in urls.items():
        COUCHBASE_CONNSTR = url
except:
    print(msg)
```

Comment: thanks ... but if first IP is .112 which is good node the code NOT working , if first IP is .110 which is bad node and 2nd one is .112 it is working . that means solution not working as expected